# How is the New Covenant consistent with Deuteronomy 4:2?

Tags: exegesis, deuteronomy

The King James Bible; Deuteronomy 4:2, says:

> Ye shall not add unto the word which I command you, neither shall ye diminish ought from it, that ye may keep the commandments of the LORD your God which I command you.

How does this make sense with the New Testament? How can there be a New set of laws given when the Old Testament clearly says not to add on?

Comment: An excellent question. Welcome to our site. One small point of clarification, which hopefully a full answer will address: The New Testament doesn't offer a new set of laws, as you suggest. As it relates to laws, it offers only perhaps a new interpretation of old laws. But it's  a good question nonetheless.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Although it is a good question, as @Flimzy says, the answer will be a matter of interpretation depending on the particular church or denomination the answerer belongs to--which makes the question off-topic on *this* site. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites).

Comment: However, in general, if Deuteronomy 4:2 meant that there should be no more books in the Bible, this would affect not only the New Testament, but every book in the *Old* Testament after Deuteronomy.

Comment: God commands Moses and the People of Israel not to add anything to or taking anything away from the covenant. He does not, of course, forbid _Himself_ to do so....

Comment: @LeeWoofenden That's a very good point.  It raises the question, though: how is this position consistent with the idea that Revelation 22: 18-19 establishes a closed canon?

Comment: @MasonWheeler That idea, too, is very flimsy. The NT canon wasn't even established at the time the book of Revelation was written. The author was clearly talking about his own book, not about Scripture as a whole. But this discussion should probably go to chat if there's a desire to continue it.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "a new set of laws"?  There weren't any new laws, Jesus himself said: "Do not think that I have come to abolish the Law or the Prophets; I have not come to abolish them but to fulfill them." Matthew 5:17

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that the New Testament neither adds nor subtracts anything from the Old Testament, the New Testament is the more perfect and fulfilled Word of God. For example, John 8:3-11.

And early in the morning he came again into the temple, and all the people came unto him; and he sat down, and taught them. And the scribes and Pharisees brought unto him a woman taken in adultery; and when they had set her in the midst, They say unto him, Master, this woman was taken in adultery, in the very act. Now Moses in the law commanded us, that such should be stoned: but what sayest thou? This they said, tempting him, that they might have to accuse him. But Jesus stooped down, and with his finger wrote on the ground, as though he heard them not. So when they continued asking him, he lifted up himself, and said unto them, He that is without sin among you, let him first cast a stone at her. And again he stooped down, and wrote on the ground. And they which heard it, being convicted by their own conscience, went out one by one, beginning at the eldest, even unto the last: and Jesus was left alone, and the woman standing in the midst. When Jesus had lifted up himself, and saw none but the woman, he said unto her, Woman, where are those thine accusers? hath no man condemned thee? She said, No man, Lord. And Jesus said unto her, Neither do I condemn thee: go, and sin no more.

Notice that Jesus said "Neither do I condemn thee, go and sin no more." rather than "Thou hast no guilt, wrongly accused were thee". Of course, there are very defined things that contrast Judaism and Christianity, things that were changed by Jesus, such as the view of the Sabbath day and clean and unclean foods.

It must be taken into account that the verse shown (Deuteronomy 4:2) says "**YE** shall not add unto the word which I command you, neither shall **YE** diminish ought from it...". This meaning that the Israelites, and mankind as a whole for that matter, shall not add unto nor diminish from the holy word of God, and not that he is not allowed to. God the father said for hundreds of years by means of prophets, that the day would come when the Messiah would come to earth and make a new and improved covenant with Jew and Gentile alike. That is what He did through His Son, Jesus. Jesus was a representative of the father and embodied that new and wonderful Covenant (John 10:30, Matthew 3:17, Romans 1:4, etc.).